# Regular expression Bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a program for comparing archives. And I have a problem with editing strings. I try to edit this with regular expressions.

All I need is to edit this line

```
archive1\sample\nothing.txt
```

and get only a name of the file without subdirectories. Like that

```
nothing.txt
```

I tried to edit a text with this expression, but it seem didn't work.

```
expr " archive1\sample\nothing.txt" : '\([a-z]*["."]*[a-z]\)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `\` as a delimiter and print the last block:

```
$ echo "archive1\sample\nothing.txt" | awk -F"\\" '{print $NF}'
nothing.txt
```

Or with Bash, use string expressions to remove everything before the last `\`:

```
$ r="archive1\sample\nothing.txt"
$ echo ${r##*\\}
nothing.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, fedorqui!

Comment: I hope either of them was useful : ) I don't know the specifics, so use the one that suits you the most!

Answer (score 1):

The `basename` program strips directories from file names:

```
$ basename 'archive1\sample\nothing.txt'
nothing.txt
```